# $_POST not working when sending HTML email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I've been figuring out what's wrong with my code. I keep getting `$_POST` not working. This is my HTML code:

```
<form id="EmailForm" action="mailForm.php" method="post" 
  onsubmit="validateForm()" enctype="text/plain">
  <div>
    Name: <input type="text" value="" name="name" size="30" />
    Email: <input type="text" value="" name="email" size="30" />
    Subject: <input type="text" value="" name="subject" size="60" />
    Message: <br />
    <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my `mailForm.php` code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mailsent = mail("admin@example.com", "$subject", "$message\n\n$name\n$email", "");
if ($mailsent) {
echo ("Your email has been sent. Thank you for using our mail form. <br />");
echo ("Name: ".$name."<br />");
echo ("Email: ".$email."<br />");
echo ("Subject: ".$subject."<br />");
echo ("Message: ".$message);
}
?>
```

So far, I can get emails sent but all emails are empty. The name or email didn't show up, but get changed to the default name from the web hosting service. No name, no email, no subject, no message. At the `mailForm.php`, I got the following only:

```
Your email has been sent. Thank you for using our mail form.   
Name:
Email:
Subject: 
Message:
```

I've tried `echo $_POST["name"]; echo $_POST["email"]` but got empty page.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to header poisoning and once live you mist likely end up being used to send out spam

Comment: @WebnetMobile: I preprocess the header fields and check for spams in the php file, I just didn't put it in this forum since it's not related to my question. Anyway, thx for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `enctype="text/plain"`:

```
<form id="EmailForm" action="mailForm.php" method="post" onsubmit="validateForm()">
```

Valid values in PHP for enctype in `<form>` tag are:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `enctype="text/plain"` in this case in your `<form>` tag ...

php Will not show your form elements in `$_POST` if you use that code.

php has a variable called `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` which will store your posted data in it as simple string when using `enctype="text/plain"`.

So your `<form>` tag in HTML code should be this:

```
<form id="EmailForm" action="mailForm.php" method="post" onsubmit="validateForm()">
```

Valid `enctype` values in `<form>` tag are:

**application/x-www-form-urlencoded:** Default. All characters are encoded before sent (spaces are converted to "+" symbols, and special characters are converted to ASCII HEX values)

**multipart/form-data:** Spaces are converted to "+" symbols, but no special characters are encoded No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control

**text/plain:** Spaces are converted to "+" symbols, but no special characters are encoded

Except `text/plain` the other 2 methods will be available as array in $_POST ...